# MongoDB count fi true in aggregate group

Tags: mongodb, grouping, aggregate, conditional-statements

I am trying, in an easy way, to average and sum some statistics, but have hit a wall!

I have a collection of documents with some statistics like this:

```
{
  "playerId": "5c6024b5031f5bc44d790e01",
  "courseId": "5b2a0ab1c6dc0f04e9a1e769",
  "gir": true,
  "data": {
    "roundHoles": [
      {
        "type": "HoleData",
        "holeNo": 1,
        "par": 3,
        "hcp": 18
      },
      {
        "type": "HoleData",
        "holeNo": 2,
        "par": 4,
        "hcp": 4
      },
      {
        "type": "HoleData",
        "holeNo": 3,
        "par": 4,
        "hcp": 8
      }
    ],
    "holeScores": [
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "strokes": 3,
        "points": 2,
        "puts": 1,
        "gir": true,
        "scrambled": false
      },
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "strokes": 5,
        "points": 1,
        "puts": 2,
        "gir": false,
        "scrambled": false
      },
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "strokes": 4,
        "points": 2,
        "puts": 1,
        "gir": false,
        "scrambled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is to get the average strokes, points and puts and the sum of scrambles and gir when true, bur only if the main "gir" is set to true.

Here is what i have come up with so far:

```
var allScores = runtimeCollection('roundScores').aggregate(
  {
      $match: { "playerId": playerId, "courseId": "5b2a0ab1c6dc0f04e9a1e769" }
  },
  {
      $unwind: {
          path: "$data.holeScores",
          includeArrayIndex: "index"
      }
  },
  {
      $group: {
          _id: "$index",
          rounds: { $sum: 1 },
          avgStrokes: { $avg: "$data.holeScores.strokes" },
          avgPoints: { $avg: "$data.holeScores.points" },
          avgPuts: { $avg: "$data.holeScores.puts" },
          sumScrambles: { $sum: "$data.holeScores.scrambled" }
      }
  }
);
```

Here is what I get from that:

```
{
  "_id": 17,
  "rounds": 18,
  "avgStrokes": 3.4444444444444446,
  "avgPoints": 1.2777777777777777,
  "avgPuts": 1.6111111111111112,
  "sumScrambles": 0
},
{
  "_id": 14,
  "rounds": 18,
  "avgStrokes": 5.388888888888889,
  "avgPoints": 2.1666666666666665,
  "avgPuts": 1.5,
  "sumScrambles": 0
},
{
  "_id": 12,
  "rounds": 18,
  "avgStrokes": 5,
  "avgPoints": 1.6111111111111112,
  "avgPuts": 1.8333333333333333,
  "sumScrambles": 0
}
```

It looks like I get the average parts just fine, but the sum does not work. I guess I have to add a condition to the sumScrambles, but not sure how?

Really hope someone can help me with this and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Firstly, you can't get the sum of boolean values, you can only get the sum of numbers. So, I'm assuming you want to add 1 whenever the scrambled value is true, in that case, you can use '[$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html)', which allows you to write conditions.

You can try something like this,

```
sumScrambles: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$data.holeScores.scrambled", true ] }, 1, 0 ] } }
```

Comment: Ahhh, that worked just fine... Thanks. Additional question. Is there anyway I can get the "par" from roundHoles into the $group?

Comment: Just for some concision... `{ $eq: [ x, true ] } ` => `x`

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) to get the averages and sum for this aggregate, all could be done in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage
since the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) operators also work in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage given that the fields are arrays.

As for the conditional sums, you can use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) on the array and then count the elements in the reduced array with [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to give you a sum.

The following pipeline demonstrates this approach

```
runtimeCollection('roundScores').aggregate([
    { '$match': { 'playerId': playerId, 'courseId': '5b2a0ab1c6dc0f04e9a1e769' } },
    { '$project': {
        'rounds': { '$size': '$data.holeScores' },
        'avgStrokes': { '$avg': '$data.holeScores.strokes' },
        'avgPoints': { '$avg': '$data.holeScores.points' },
        'avgPuts': { '$avg': '$data.holeScores.puts' },
        'avgPars': { '$avg': '$data.roundHoles.par' },
        'sumScrambles': { 
            '$size': {
                '$filter': {
                    'input': '$data.holeScores',
                    'cond': '$$this.scrambled'
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

Comment: While trying this I get this error: Function aggregate does not accept parameters (object).

Comment: I see, I take it `runtimeCollection('roundScores')` returns a mongo collection and the [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method on the collection takes an array as an argument for the pipeline parameter which is what the above is doing. Not so sure whether the error is related to the above since it clearly states it doesn't like an object as parameter but did you try running the pipeline without the array?

Comment: I am able to run it without the array, but then it takes the average of all strokes for all rounds. Any ideas?

Comment: nothing else worked for me except this. many thanks :)